# Illegal parameter number in definition of \next when using # in a tcolorbox with parameters

Tags: tcolorbox

Here is a working example (with a strange behaviour though):

```
\documentclass{article}

\usepackage[listings]{tcolorbox}

\newtcblisting{termbox}[1][\normalsize]{%
  listing options={basicstyle=#1},
}

\begin{document}

\begin{termbox}
  aa
\end{termbox}

\begin{termbox}[]
  aa
\end{termbox}

\begin{termbox}[\footnotesize]
  aa
\end{termbox}

\end{document}
```

[image]

I don't understand why for the first `termbox`, by not providing `[]` the tab is not interpreted as part of the listing environment and is thus not displayed.

I tried, then, to display a listing environment starting with `#` (and since the first tab is read by LaTeX I was almost sure it was going to go bad)

```
\documentclass{article}

\usepackage[listings]{tcolorbox}

\newtcblisting{termbox}[1][\normalsize]{%
  listing options={basicstyle=#1},
}

\begin{document}

\begin{termbox}
  # aa
\end{termbox}

\end{document}
```

```
 ! Illegal parameter number in definition of \next.
<to be read again> 
                   }
l.12   #
         aa
```

I tried to add `[]` (same with `[\footnotesize]`) and see!, a new error appears:

```
\documentclass{article}

\usepackage[listings]{tcolorbox}

\newtcblisting{termbox}[1][\normalsize]{%
  listing options={basicstyle=#1},
}

\begin{document}

\begin{termbox}[]
  # aa
\end{termbox}

\end{document}
```

```
! You can't use `macro parameter character #' in internal vertical mode.
l.1   #
        aa
```

Is it something I'm doing wrong or a bug in the package? Is there a way to circumvent it other than my actual solution (I created two tcblistings, one with `\normalsize` and the other one with `\footnotesize` and no parameters)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The error appears in the lower part, where the code is *executed*. I don't think you want it unless you're showing correct LaTeX code.

```
\documentclass{article}

\usepackage[listings]{tcolorbox}

\newtcblisting{termbox}[1][\normalsize]{%
  listing options={basicstyle=#1},
  listing only,
}

\begin{document}

\begin{termbox}[]
#  aa
\end{termbox}

\begin{termbox}[\footnotesize]
#  aa
\end{termbox}

\end{document}
```

However, I'm afraid you need `[]` if you plan to start with `#`.

[image]

You may want to use the `xparse` interface that allows avoiding to scan the input to find the possible `[`.

```
\documentclass{article}

\usepackage[listings,xparse]{tcolorbox}

\NewTCBListing{termbox}{!O{\normalsize}}{%
  listing options={basicstyle=#1},
  listing only,
}

\begin{document}

\begin{termbox}
#  aa
\end{termbox}

\begin{termbox}[]
#  aa
\end{termbox}

\begin{termbox}[\footnotesize]
#  aa
\end{termbox}

\end{document}
```

[image]

Here the limitation is that you're not allowed to have a space in front of `[`, so no

```
\begin{termbox} [...]
```

but it shouldn't be a problem.

Comment: Great answer, thank you very much!